# Julia@1.0.0: How to get installed Pkg.uuid in REPL

Tags: julia

I want to use `Base.compilecache`.
It needs `PkgId(UUID)`. But I don't know how to get installed Pkg.uuid in REPL.
https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.0.0/base/base/#Base.compilecache

I tried `Pkg.PackageSpec` but can't get UUID.
https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/Pkg/#Pkg.PackageSpec

```
julia> using Pkg

julia> Pkg.status()
Status `~/.julia/environments/v1.0/Project.toml`
[8f4d0f93] Conda v1.0.1
[7073ff75] IJulia v1.9.3

julia> Pkg.PackageSpec("Conda")
PackageSpec(name=Conda)

julia> Pkg.PackageSpec("Conda").uuid
UUID("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
```

My goal is to call `Base.compilecache` at Docker file.

Julia v0.6.4 code

```
julia -e "Base.compilecache(\"JSON\")"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Base.identify_package("Conda")`.

Comment: Thanks. `Base.compilecache(Base.identify_package("Conda"))` works.